# Split Reducer in Big App

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to organize My reducers (combineReducers) by different logic part in my app.

Example

```
user: ...,
app: ...,
news: ...,
etc.
```

But have some problem with it. I build a big like social Media app (not exactly) and I have only 2 reducers like `app` and `user`, all logic in app work near user (messages, games, friends..) and I dont know how to split them.

It will be great if anyone have an experience with it and can advise something to me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html)? You just need to define 2 reducer functions separately, combine them and use the combined version where you create the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to split appReducer and userReducer, then:

```
//appReducer.js
export default () => {
  ...logic
}

//userReducer.js
export default () => {
  ...logic
}

//your store
import appReducer from './appReducer';
import userReducer from './userReducer';
const store = createStore(combineReducers({ app: appReducer, user: userReducer}));
```

If you're asking how to split your userReducer because you feel like the reducer is getting too big, then you have to take them out of userReducer and make messagesReducer, friendsReducer, etc... Just because you feel like they're part of "user" object doesn't mean you have to have them all in the same userReducer. And that's what the action type is there for you and what flux/redux data flow helps you.

Comment: Yes, I mean second part. But how to choose what gonna be in User reducer and what not. I know thats "non good question" but any article about this ?

Comment: I haven't seen anything comprehensive, but specifically in your case I would say anything that is about "user", such as email address, username, id, profileImageURL, etc should go directly under userReducer and other thing that user "has", like messages, friends, games can have their own reducer. I know you could argue that everything is "has", but I would consider the expected size of the data and complexity in terms of how often the data change over time as well as the number of ways that can affect the data during the session of the app to see if something deserves its own reducer.

Comment: e.g. messages will grow as the user receives them and there can be many ways to receive messages, whereas email address doesn't change that often or maybe never and you are very likely to have only one way to update it even if you do.

Answer (score 3):

What you want, I think, is for your code to be maintainable. Having a new feature added to a specific part of code, or alternatively finding that bug that's been haunting your users should be easy.

Splitting your reducers is a good way to go about this. You know you have divided the code up well if you know how to name a reducer and exactly what kind of logic goes there.  This helps future developers easily find that file they need to modify when fixing a bug.

You haven't given enough information for me to help you decide how to split it up but here are some rules of thumb.

1. **Think of your components**. if mapping the entire "user" means that the component displaying the messages also has to digest the "friends" property in that reducer, then maybe you should divide it into messageReducer and friendsReducer. This is good for you because changes to messages doesn't need to affect any components other then those subscribed to that reducer.
2. **Think of your actions**. if 1 reducer listens to 100 actions, then your code will get hard to follow since you've build an exhausting API to your store. Also if you have exactly one listener to 1 action, then you're not working correctly with actions, you're just building a long command stack. What you want is several reducers listening to the same action. For example: an ajax request has finished, this is a good time to - modify the list; switch the network progress state to done;send an additional analytics event; etc. 3 totally separate actions that couldn't care less about the rest.
3. **Think of your ajax** - your server responses are either large payloads that contain lots of different types of data, or a single piece of information. Having the "friends" reducer handle the "friends" API will be easy to follow, much easier than having the "user" reducer follow the entire server API.
4. **Think of your complexity**. If a user reducer handles 5% of all actions and the rest is just "friends" actions, then maybe you need to split up the friends actions to "suggested friends", "added friends", etc. 
   This is where you will hear a lot of different opinions - personally I'd rather have two reducers, both listening to the "add friend" event, and each doing their thing (in this csae the suggested friends needs to filter out the added friend and the "Added " needs to add the friend"). This is much cleaner then a long event handling function where both these things happen. A bug in the "suggested friends" is clearly in the "suggested friends reducer".

Anyway, that's my 2 cents. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine as many reducers as you want

**userReducer.js**

```
export default combineReducers({
  messages, 
  games, 
  friends
});
```

**appReducer.js**

```
export default combineReducers({
  ...otherStaff
});
```

**mainReducer.js**

```
import user from './userReducer';
import app from './appReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  app,
  user
});
```

But it's a good practice to keep your state normalised and avoid deep nesting